# Dynamic post call giving error 404 on angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular5, httpclient

I am making a post call, where post parameter getting from another get call.
If I pass the post parameter manually its working fine.

```
doPost(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(this.URL+ '/GetEmp', {emp:[{"empId":8106, "name":"xxxxx"}]});    
}
```

But when I am calling it dynamically its showing 404 error

```
doPost(val): Observable<any> {
    this.postD = JSON.stringify(val);
    return this.http.post(this.URL+ '/GetEmp', {emp:this.postD});    
}
```

Here I am calling like this

```
this.configs.doPost(pval).subscribe(
    data => {this.post = data['org']},           
    err => console.error(err),
    () => console.log('done loading employee' + this.post)
);
```

Requirement is that I am making one GET request, through that I am getting the value and populated the drop-down, once I select the value from drop-down, this value needs to use for parameter in post call.

Here I am able to get the value from drop-down, but once I am passing it through post request its giving `404` error.

Please help on this.

Comment: can you paste the complete `error`

Comment: try not to stringify it,  return `this.http.post(this.URL+ '/GetEmp', {emp: val}); `

Comment: POST http://myapiURL 404 (Generic)
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: "Generic",url: "myapiURL", ok: false, …}

Comment: can u show what u are calling after select?

Comment: Thank you for the response, I have updated the code and removed the stringify and its working.

Comment: I added an answer. Please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hTTP post` requires an object so please dont `stringify` it

```
doPost(val): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(this.URL+ '/GetEmp', { emp: val });    
}
```

**Here is the syntax:**

`post(url: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs) :`

- **Observable url:** This is HTTP URL using which we post data
  to the server.
- **body:** This is the object which we need to post to the server.
- **options:** This is optional. Here we pass the instance of
  RequestOptionsArgs that uses headers.
- **Observable:** This is the return type of Http.post().